# Validate the URL like http://localhost and file:///sdcard/file.txt

Tags: android, regex, validation, url

I was looking for URL validation methods on Android. This one is pretty useless:

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

This one works pretty good for web url's but fails with http://localhost or file:///sdcard/file.txt

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()
```

Is there a better URL validator to use?

Comment: You better make one your self that does what you want.

Comment: Is there anything particular you want and library is not providing?

Comment: I just want to check all kind of full URL entered by users and used in Webview as valid according to scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

Comment: I found a great URL regex collection here: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex and used a modified diegoperini regex for my needs.